# Differentiating a Swift value type from an object i.e. reference type at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is there some way to tell apart value types (e.g. tuples, enums and structs including primitives) from object also known as reference types in Swift at runtime either using Swift or the Objective-C runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to check if a variable is an instance of a class:

```
object_isClass(type(of: yourVariable))
```

It uses [type(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type), which returns the dynamic type of the variable.

Here are some tests:

```
let a = 1

let b = ("a", 2.3)

enum MyEnum { case one; case two }
let c = MyEnum.one

struct MyStruct { let property: Int }
let d = MyStruct(property: 0)

class MyClass {}
let e = MyClass()

object_isClass(type(of: a))  //false
object_isClass(type(of: b))  //false
object_isClass(type(of: c))  //false
object_isClass(type(of: d))  //false
object_isClass(type(of: e))  //true
```